# does complex analysis entirely depend on the strong definition of complex derivative?

Tags: complex-analysis

This is a question about the foundation of complex analysis.

**Question 1:** Is it fair to say that almost all of complex analysis is derived from the rather strong definition of complex derivatives?

---

By definition, I mean that the derivative at a point $z$ is the same no matter from which [direction](https://complex-analysis.com/content/complex_differentiation.html) the limit is taken.

By complex analysis, I mean things like the Cauchy residue theorem and analytic continuity.

If the complex derivative was defined as dependent on the direction of the limit, then things like the residue theorem and analytic continuity, would not be possible.

---

**Question 2**: Is it reasonable to consider a different complex analysis where the derivative does deepened on direction? Is it useful? Why was the strong requirement considered natural?

---

UPDATE - the answer on HSM.stack is also very helpful: https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13805/history-of-definition-of-complex-derivative

Comment: There is further complex analysis where you consider functions that don't vanish under Cauchy Riemann with theorems like $$\int_{\partial \Omega}f dz = 2i\iint_\Omega \partial_{\bar{z}}f dx\wedge dy$$ If you view complex analytic functions as a subset of real analytic functions on $R^2$ then effectively the requirement we are imposing is that the derivative, or Jacobian matrix, is a complex number in matrix form.

Comment: It is strange to me that this is being downvoted, since this is a very natural question, not overtly addressed in many discussions of complex analysis. If @NinadMunshi would elaborate their comment, I'd certainly upvote that answer.

Comment: the notion of derivative makes sense in any topological field as the usual limit of a ratio (for example p-adic numbers where there are lots of cool/weird phenomena  and very counterintuitive results for "familiar" functions like the exponential, the logarithm etc); it just happens that for the complex numbers this has strong properties; the notion of directional derivatives and/or differential makes sense in any topological vector space over a topological field (for example the complex plane as a real two-dimensional field, but also a Banach space say) but that is in general a weaker notion

Comment: Paul and @conrad - thanks for your input. So you're saying that actually the direction-invariant definition of a derivative is indeed natural because there is a more abstract notion in a topological field? And that the directional derivative is not the natural definition even if it is more familiar to those of us coming from basic maths with its partial derivatives. Where can I learn more about derivatives in a topological field?

Comment: please can whoever downvoted explain why?

Comment: The theory of Multivariable calculus allows one to talk about what it means for a function $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ to be differentiable. I guess you may count this as a version of complex analysis where the derivative does depend on the direction. If one imposes the condition that the jacobian $Df$ at any point is a complex scalar, then one gets the best of both worlds. i.e. A theory which is not too general to allow lots of uninteresting bizarre objects and not too restrictive to the point of triviality.

Comment: @Amr - I think you've hit the nail on the head. If the definition was just multivariate calculus in 2-d real space then it wouldn't be that interesting. Your comment has been very enlightening.

Comment: the answer on HSM.stack adds usefully to the answer https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/13805/history-of-definition-of-complex-derivative